# Java Heap Space: Out of Memory Error - Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using App Engine Standard, with Java 8 language. Whenever I read a file from Cloud Storage and convert it into a String, I get an out-of-memory error. Here's the snippet:

```
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("<Bucket Name>", "<file_name>");  // file size is 19MB
    byte[] content = storage.readAllBytes(blobId);
    String contentString = new String(content, UTF_8); // this is causing the error
```

This is the log trace:

```
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: Error for /transform (JettyLogger.java:29) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:215) 
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:465) 
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:517) 
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.NullSandboxPlugin$LogStream.flush(NullSandboxPlugin.java:600) 
    at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:338) 
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.NullSandboxPlugin$LogPrintStream.print(NullSandboxPlugin.java:546) 
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806) 
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.NullSandboxPlugin$LogPrintStream.println(NullSandboxPlugin.java:468) 
    at com.gcds.app.controller.BaseController.doGet(BaseController.java:49) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772) 
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) 
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) 
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) 
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) 
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
```

Is there any way out of it?

Comment: Could you edit the post to add the trace of the error?

Comment: Which instance size are you using?

Comment: Have posted the error trace

Comment: How do we see the instance size in appengine console

Comment: Following up with @DaveW.Smith, the instance size depends on the class you are using. To check which class is being used through the Cloud Console, go to the App Engine menu and select "Versions". Check the version you are running right now (it has "Serving" status) and, on the right side, on the "Config" column, select "View" and look for the instance class value. With [this table](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) you will be able to identify how much memory your instance has. Please confirm which result you got when checking this.

Comment: Have you identified your instance class? If so, could you please update the question indicating which one do you have now? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. However, it can be solved by using  in appengine-web.xml. I'm using AppEngine Java SDK. Depend on your , AppEngine will assign necessary instance for your application.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref

One problem is that it can not be applied to the local development server. When I try to debug the current application, I experience the same error. In maven build environment, it's not easy to do that. If you use IDE such as Eclipse, there are pathway to avoid that. In my case, editing "Debug Configuration" with preferred memory size can resolve this issue.

Please find my "Debug Configuration" as following,
[Program Argumennts]

```
--allow_remote_shutdown --disable_update_check --no_java_agent D:\workspace\xxxx
```

[VM Arguements]

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx8182m -Duse_jetty9_runtime=true  -D--enable_all_permissions=true   -Ddatastore.backing_store=D:\workspace\\local_db.bin
```

Comment: In my case it worked, in appengine-web.xml i added <instance-class>F2</instance-class>. Thanks.